# PeoplePicker - Search specific forest

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker

We have 4 domains and I would like to limit the people search to one specific domain say (`intl.com`).

I don't know if this MS article (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263460(office.12).aspx) takes care of the requirements.

Can anyone please suggest?

I tried running `getproperty` but all I get is

```
<property exits="no">
```

Comment: on which domain you sharepoint server reside?becuase that domain is default in the people picker

Comment: server is on Tangent.net domain also, i am trying to get existing forests via this command stsadm.exe -o getproperty -propertyname peoplepicker-searchadforests -url http://home.magicsales.il but it keeps saying <Property Exist="no">

Comment: Your quoted stsadm-command does not query "existing forests". It displays any configured domains or forests, which get used by peoplepicker. "no" means that you did not configure any additional domains or forests except the one SharePoint resides in. You might want to use the following command to add additional domains to your peoplepicker: stsadm -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "domain:yourmissingdomain.com" -url "http://home.magicsales.il"